# performing load test for encrypted application using Jmeter version5

Tags: jmeter

how to do load test for encrypted application using Jmeter, where the application is encrypted across all pages? The application is developed in angular JS technology.

Comment: "Encrypted application" can be 300.000 things under the sun. Could you explain better your stack and security schemes?

Comment: Please edit your answer with more information. I assume by "encrypted application" you mean that it uses https and maybe also encrypts traffic between the web server and the data store. What have you tried? What were your results? Without more information we can't help you.

Comment: while recording the encrypted using jmeter we are not able to view the actual data after recording it displays in encrypted mode while do playback we are getting the empty response though we have added SSL certificate.As it has  random encryption keys where it generates the certificate   while accessing page.

Comment: The data has been encrypted using RSA token on this application.

Answer (score 1):

If by `encrypted` you mean [SSL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/SSL) or [TLS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Transport_Layer_Security) then you don't even need to do anything, according to [SSL Encryption chapter of the JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#opt_ssl)

> **The JMeter HTTP samplers are configured to accept all certificates, whether trusted or not, regardless of validity periods, etc.** This is to allow the maximum flexibility in testing servers.
>
> If the server requires a [client certificate](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates/), this can be provided.
>
> There is also the [SSL Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SSL_Manager), for greater control of certificates.